# Android : How to stop music service of my app, if another app plays music.?

Tags: android, audio, service

1) In an android project, I have written a service that plays music at the background. The problem is when my application is playing music at the background and another application(music player) plays music, both the audios play simultaneously. I want to stop playing the music in my application, if any other app plays the music. How do I deal with this.?

Answer (score 8):

**This is how I solved the issue.**

Implement `OnAudioFocusChangeListener listener`

Initialise `AudioManager` like

```
private AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

**Request Audio focus**

```
mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

@Overide the following method of `OnAudioFocusChangeListener`

```
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) 
{
    switch (focusChange) 
   {
    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
        resumePlayer(); // Resume your media player here
        break;
    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
    case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
        pausePlayer();// Pause your media player here 
        break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This concept is called **audio focus** in Android.

In broad terms, it means that only one app can have audio focus at one point in time, and that you should relinquish if it asked to (for example if a phone call arrives, or another app wants to play music, &c).

To do this, you need to register an [`OnAudioFocusChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener.html).

Basically, you must:

- Request audio focus before starting playback.
- Only start playback if you effectively obtain it.
- Abandon focus when you stop playback.
- Handle audio focus loss, either by lowering volume temporarily ("ducking") or stopping playback altogether.

Please check the [Managing Audio Focus](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus) article in the Android documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private boolean reqAudioFocus() {
        boolean gotFocus = false;
        int audioFocus = am.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
        if (audioFocus == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
            gotFocus = true;
        } else {
            gotFocus = false;
        }
        return gotFocus;
    }
```

This will request for audio focus when you start your application and other music app is already running .So this will stop the already running app and start yours.

```
 if (reqAudioFocus()) {

            mPlayer.prepareAsync();
        }
```

paste this where you want to prepare your mediaplayer.

For the other way round that is your app should stop when other app is played

use

```
public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {

        if (focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS) {
            am.abandonAudioFocus(this);
            mPlayer.stop();


        }

    }
```

where "am" is your AudioManager Instance.

Dont forget to implement AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener